# SQLite or Realm

Tags: sqlite, realm

I'm having a big question, using SQLite or Realm as database.

I'm creating an android application with react-native that needs a database to store data. So I would like to know which database to use, SQLite or Realm.

Comment: That's, like, totally up to you man

Answer (score 3):

I work with SQLite and realm and in my experience, this depends on what you going to do with your database.
in my experience, I found the realm

- easy to use
- really fast
- and easy to encript

but also

- didn't have a complete query stuff like FTS or update for a bunch of columns

in my opinion, if you don't do something fancy with your database in query stuff select realm otherwise select SQLite.
hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

Android default database is SQLiteDatabase. here is more details

[link 1](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) [link 2](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) [link 3](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/index.html) [linl 4](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Persisting-Data-to-the-Device)

Comment: I want to launch the iOS app later. Do you recommend SQLite?

Comment: Google recommended to use SqlLite for android. i am android developer , don't know about the ios.